# PHP - Координаты точки, из которой пришел http-запрос

Tags: php, http

Есть сервер, пусть он находится в Москве. К нему пришел http запрос из Ростова. Можно ли на сервере узнать широту и долготу, с которой был отправлен запрос к серверу (в данном случае это приблизительные координаты Ростова)

Comment: Нужно "вычислить по IP" в буквальном смысле

Answer (score 1):

Да, можете воспользоваться библиотекой [sxGeo](https://sypexgeo.net/ru/docs/) Возможна работа и через [REST API](https://sypexgeo.net/ru/api/). Пример работы можете посмотреть [здесь](https://sypexgeo.net/ru/demo/)

Comment: В ответ не помешает добавить пример кода, одних ссылок, обычно, недостаточно)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Дак вот же он, [только по ссылке](https://sypexgeo.net/ru/docs/), сразу в документации - и создание объекта, и определение адреса, и освобождение памяти

Comment: Да, только бывают случаи, когда через несколько лет авторы проекта решают перенести документацию на другой домен и даже сменить название продукта. В этом случае все ссылки станут недействительны. А вот если код в вопросе останется, то ответ всё ещё будет полезен)